# Express custom log crashes while using express.static

Tags: node.js, express, static

I'm currently trying to log the full end response of every Express request with a simple middleware function like this:

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    const startTime = new Date();
    const oldEnd = res.end;

    res.end = (chunks, encoding) => {
        const responseTime = new Date() - startTime;
        res.set('Server-Timing', `total;dur=${responseTime}`);
        console.log(req.path, `Response Time: ${responseTime}`);
        res.end = oldEnd;
        res.end(chunks, encoding);
    };

    next();
}
```

This code works fine with normal Express endpoints but when I try to serve a static file like this: `app.use('/static/path', express.static('path'))` I get the following error:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

This happens because of the `res.set` for the server timing but this means `express.static` uses `.end()` twice? When I `console.log` in my middleware function it only gets called once.

I'm using NodeJS 10 and Express 4.16.4

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Please elaborate _"trying to log the full end response"_? Are you trying to measure the elapsed time for each request?

Comment: I'm trying to log some parameters from the request and response object like: status, headers and the total response time. This works fine but just doesn't work while using `express.static`. Because of this I overwrote the `res.end` function and call it again after I'm finished with it. Setting the response header is causing this problem while it clearly gets set before the `res.end`.

Answer (score 1):

`res.end` is not called twice.

[serve-static](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static/blob/master/index.js#L125) is streaming the file to the client and when the first chunk of the file is written to the stream, the headers will be sent. From the nodejs docs:

> **[response.writeHead](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_writehead_statuscode_statusmessage_headers)**
>
> If response.write() or response.end() are called before calling this, the implicit/mutable headers will be calculated and call this function.

So it is not possible to set headers after the stream has started to send data to the client. But it is possible to pass a [setHeader](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static#setheaders) function in the options to serve-static.

```
express.static('./public', {
  setHeaders: (res, path, stat) => {
    const responseTime = new Date() - res.locals.startTime;
    res.set('Server-Timing', `total;dur=${responseTime}`);
  },
});
```

However, since the headers are sent off at the start of the steam this is not accurate response time. More of a response time for the just the headers.